# Storing value in array in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter-3

I came across a problem where i want to store the id's in array in a single session like array(['docid']=>1,['docid']=>2,['docid']=>3,['docid']=>4,['docid']=>5,['docid']=>6,['docid']=>7) like this way i want the id's in single session when i click on the link, Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here is my code:-

```
public function addtoshortlist()
{

     $shortlist=array('docid'=>$_GET['id']);
    $this->session->set_userdata('shortlist',$shortlist);
    print_r($this->session->userdata('shortlist'));
    //$this->session->userdata('shortlist')['docid'];

    redirect($this->agent->referrer());
}
```

Comment: you can not create an array with the same key. If all are docid then store it as array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7); and process.

Comment: I had  tried everything from my side but it didn't works for me. can you please explain with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function addtoshortlist()
{
     $shortlist=array('docid' => array($_GET['id']));
     if(!$this->session->userdata('shortlist')['docid'])
     {
          $this->session->set_userdata('shortlist',$shortlist);
     }else{
          $session = $this->session->userdata('shortlist')['docid'];
          if(!in_array($_GET['id'],$session))
          $session[]=$_GET['id'];
          $this->session->set_userdata('shortlist',array('docid'=>$session));
     }
     print_r($this->session->userdata('shortlist'));

    redirect($this->agent->referrer());
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same id and the array is is having only one value but i want an array inside array which contains or which stored all docid's in the array. your code is not working...!!

Comment: well i am getting this" Array ( [0] => 9 [2] => 10 [3] => 11 [4] => 12 [5] => 13 [6] => 9 ) "answer with what your updated answer 



but what i want answer in this "Array(['docid']=>array(1,2,3,4,5,6)) ; "format.

Also i do not want repeated id's like i am getting with your answer you can see this above on first array i am getting id 9 in 0th position and on 6th position as well i do not want repeated id's if once user added on id then  i do not want that user will add the same id again and again..!! I just want to allow him to add the id only once.

Comment: woaaahh Thank's Vinie It work's for me exactly the way i want :) thank's a lot  for help ..! :)